# iTerm2: Upon maximizing a pane within the window, the pane still does not resize/reflow

Tags: iterm2

I am using iTerm2 (Build 3.4.9beta1) - but, the same behavior is present in iTerm2 3.4.8 which is the currently released version.

When I open new panes within the same tab, everything is fine. But, when I maximize the *pane* within the tab/window, though the pane expands to take up the full width and height of the window, the text does not reflow. The only hack that I found was the go into full-screen mode, and then back out - for the resize/reflow to take effect. This was working a few weeks ago. Wanted to find out if this is being experienced by others are well.

*This is NOT related to tmux - I dont use tmux or screen at all*